# Homework: Cannot figure out how to code multiple nested loop

Tags: java, nested-loops

I have to write code to print the following:

999999999888888887777777666666555554444333221
999999999888888887777777666666555554444333221
999999999888888887777777666666555554444333221
999999999888888887777777666666555554444333221

I can get as far as

999999999888888888777777777666666666555555555444444444333333333222222222111111111
999999999888888888777777777666666666555555555444444444333333333222222222111111111
999999999888888888777777777666666666555555555444444444333333333222222222111111111
999999999888888888777777777666666666555555555444444444333333333222222222111111111

but cannot figure out how to make each iteration decrease by one

Here is what I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{       
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    { 
        for(int j = 9; j >= 1; j--) 
        {               
            System.out.print(j);

            for(int k = 9; k > 0; k--) 
            {                   
                System.out.print(j);            
            }               
        }
        System.out.println();               
    }                       
}
```

Here is my understanding of what I have so far: The first loop (i) controls the number of lines to make, while the first nested loop (j) prints the  numbers 9 through 1 in a descending order.  The third nested loop (k) decides how many times to print each number.  What I need to do now is decrease that number by one each time it iterates through the loop. To be honest, I kind of get lost in the code from here.  I know I need another for loop that will cause my k loop to decrease by one every iteration but cannot figure out where to put it to make it doo so. I tried to nest a loop inside of the k loop like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{       
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {                                   
            for(int j = 9; j >= 1; j--)             
            {
                System.out.print(j);

                for(int k = 9; k > 0; k--) 
                {                   
                    System.out.print(j);

                for(int l = 9; l > 0; l--) 
                {                   
                    System.out.print(j);            
                }               
            }               
    }
    System.out.println();               
}
```

but that didn't work. I tried putting it before the k loop but that didn't work either. So now I've basically confused myself and am at a complete loss of what to do.

Comment: Edit the innermost loop, don't compare it with 0. Hint, hint

Comment: You were close. Don't let the spoilsports on SO ruin your sense of achievement by posting too quickly. There is no better feeling than the feeling of getting it right after trying, hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to recognize is that you want `j` `'j'` characters printed out.  Your `k` for loop can start at `j` and go down to `0`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{ 
    for(int j = 9; j >= 1; j--) 
    {               
        System.out.print(j);

        for(int k = j; k > 0; k--) 
        {                   
            System.out.print(j);            
        }               
    }
    System.out.println();               
}
```

Comment: Thank you and everyone else for helping me with this.  After I seen how to do it, it seems like a big "duh" but for the world of me I couldn't see it.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In example 1, where you have

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{       
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    { 
        for(int j = 9; j >= 1; j--) 
        {               
            System.out.print(j);

            for(int k = 9; k > 0; k--) 
            {                   
                System.out.print(j);            
            }               
        }
        System.out.println();               
    }                       
}
```

You print out 8 9 times because the `k` variable starts at 9. Start it at a value that decreases as `j` goes down.

Answer (score 0):

You were actually really close, you just shouldn't write things out twice, and you should make sure you write out the number as many times as the number itself, not 9 times each time.

Once you managed to fix that, you should read this, maybe it helps.
Note:
THIS ANSWER IS A **SPOILER**.

```
999999999888888887777777666666555554444333221 
999999999888888887777777666666555554444333221 
999999999888888887777777666666555554444333221 
999999999888888887777777666666555554444333221
```

Think about it:

You need  to do `4` times, that you `go from 9 to 1`, and write the numbers out `9...1` times for each corresponding number.

So as you said, you need a loop for `n` where `n` is 4:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{
    //...more code here
}
```

Then afterwards, you need to loop from 9 to 1 inside that loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{
    for(int j = 9; j >= 1; j--)
    {
       //...more code here
    }
}
```

Then you just need to write the number out as many times as the number itself:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{
    for(int j = 9; j >= 1; j--)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < j; k++)
        {
             //more code here
        }
    }
}
```

And thus you just need to add the lines that would write a newline after 1 has been printed out, and the printing itself, and that's it! You can do that too, though. You know how.

Comment: I think having the third loop run from `0 to j` is much clearer than the `k = j; k--` approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
int k=10;
for(int i=9; i> 0; i--)
{
k--;
j=k;
while (j> 0)
{
System.out.printf("%d", i);
j--;
}
}
System.out.printf("%n");
```

store this in a method and call it as and when desired, or call it 4 times in your case

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   for(int j = 9; j >= 1; j--)         
    for(int k = j; k > 0; k--) 
        System.out.print(j);            
   System.out.println();     
 }
```

Comment: It would be a far better answer if you pointed out the mistakes op made along with your answer.